# <p:ajax /> for calling a java method when a javascript function return ture

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, primefaces

I am using the PrimeFaces and JSF recently.

Need your suggestion for calling a java method from  depend on condition.

Please find details of problem below.
Need ajax functionality for calling a java method when a javascript return true else not call java method.

For example first ajax call a js function and check its return value,if it is true then call the java method else it would not call java method.

Comment: Please take a look at [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example] (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a remote command

`<p:remoteCommand name="rc" actionListener="#{yourBean.yourJavaMethod}" />`

to call it from your javascript

`if(someCondition) 
   { rc(); }`